# Adding a searchable database of webpages from my website. What to use?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website in which members of a gaming community are highlighted for achievements. When a gamer achieves certain goals, they send me the screenshot and I make a page on my website

(website.com/players/username)

I want to make a database of usernames, and add a search function that will bring up the username when searched. I then want viewers to be able to click the username and be brought to their page.

How do I do this? I have been watching Mysql tutorials but I'm not sure if this is what I need to be doing. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*use mysql's select and a form*

**html**

```
<form method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**mysql query after submit**

```
    <?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '".$_POST['name']."'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo '<a href="website.com/players/'.$_POST['name'].'"></a>';
      echo "<br>";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
     }
    ?>
```